# CryptoJS using actual key, not password

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Trying to encrypt a string using CryptoJS and an actual key (not passphrase).

Documentation says:

> For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and
> used to derive an actual key and IV. Or you can pass a WordArray that
> represents the actual key. If you pass the actual key, you must also
> pass the actual IV.

But I could not find any examples on how to pass a WordArray and IV.

I need it to be a key because it will be pre-shared. I'm trying to validate by decrypting using https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption

Comment: [Here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv) is an example how to parse a hex encoded string into a `WordArray` using CryptoJS's Hex encoder. Besides there are other [encoders](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) for Base64, Utf8 etc.

Comment: The IV is not supposed to be secret, but needs to be unique for CTR mode and unpredictable for CBC mode. It is usually prepended to the ciphertext during encryption and sliced off during decryption.